# PyQt GUI items outside its main class

Tags: python

how can i use GUI components like **pushButton** outside MainApp Class any idea?

**Code**

```
class MainApp(QMainWindow, FORM_CLASS):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
      QMainWindow.__init__(self)
      self.setupUi(self)
      self.btnConnect.clicked.connect(self.connect)
```

Comment: you mean access `btnConnect` outside the class or what?¿

Comment: yes and other components too i want to use them in anothrer classes

Comment: you want those instances? then pass a reference to the other classes, either of the Mainapp class or the widgets themselves but you will probably be doing something wrong sine that is not as PyQt is intended to work

Comment: can you give example by code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the references to other objects like this:

```
class MainApp(QMainWindow, FORM_CLASS):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
      QMainWindow.__init__(self)
      self.setupUi(self)
      self.btnConnect.clicked.connect(self.connect)

class MyOtherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, the_button):
        self.btn = the_button

myApp = MainApp()
my_other_class = MyOtherClass(myApp.btnConnect)
```

Comment: @emadali, If you think it was a valid reply please consider to mark it as so ;)

Comment: can i send you the whole code and you tell me how to create it in correct PyQt way?

Comment: @emadali, this is not how SO works, but you can post another question for any specic doubt and I would gladly answer if I know the answer to it. Anyway, you should consider using slots and making your classes react to other classes messages instead of sharing objects between them :)

Comment: i have another question what does **self** refer to in the MainApp class?

Comment: it is refer to the instance of the MainApp class